# Issues with ApplicationHttpRequest and getParameter

Tags: java, servlets, java-8, tomcat8

I have recently changes our app from Java 1.7 and Tomcat 7 to Java 1.8 and Tomcat 8.

The issue i am facing is that when one servlet call another the request parameter is now an **ApplicationHttpRequest** instead of the **HttpServletRequest** as it was before. This should not be an issue but for some different behaviour for the same methods.

For example request.getParameter("param1") will return a null for the HttpServletRequest if the parameter is not in the request.

But for ApplicationHttpRequest it with throw an exaction like so; *java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;*

If the parameter does exist in the request then they behave the same.

I have written a utility method to handle the issue. But i was wondering if there is an configuration change i can do to get the original HttpServletRequest back?

```
public static String getRequestParameter(HttpServletRequest request, String key) {
    if (request == null || StringUtils.isBlank(key)) return  null;

    try {
        return request.getParameter(key);
    } catch (ClassCastException e1) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationHttpRequest comes with Tomcat from Apache and is a wrapper which extends HttpServletRequestWrapper.  Try changing the dynamic web module version to an earlier version.

It is also possible that you have got your IDE to automatically import the wrong classes.

Here is a full list of classes which should be imported to ensure that HTTPServletRequest is used:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
```